# Code for Chi-square distribution function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, statistics, distribution, chi-squared

I have been looking for usable and full code for `chi-square` distribution in Delphi. There are some codes via net, but usually they don't work or have missing parts, do not compile etc.. There are also some libraries, but I'm interested about some code that I just can simply implement.

I've found something almost working. Some german parts have been fixed, it compiles and it gives `p-values` for most of the data:

```
function LnGamma (x : Real) : Real;    
const 
  a0 =  0.083333333096; 
  a1 = -0.002777655457; 
  a2 =  0.000777830670; 
  c  =  0.918938533205;     
var  
  r : Real;     
begin 
  r := (a0 + (a1 + a2 / sqr(x)) / sqr(x)) / x; 
  LnGamma := (x - 0.5) * ln(x) - x + c + r; 
end; 

function LnFak (x : Real) : Real;     
var 
  z : Real;     
begin 
  z := x+1; 
  LnFak := LnGamma(z); 
end; 

function Reihe (chi : Real; f : Real) : Real;
  const MaxError = 0.0001;    
var
  Bruch,
  Summe,
  Summand : Real;
  k, i    : longint;    
begin
  Summe := 1;
  k := 1;
  repeat
    Bruch := 1;
    for i := 1 to k do
      Bruch := Bruch * (f + 2 * i);
    Summand := power(chi, 2 * k) / Bruch;
    Summe := Summe + Summand;
    k := succ(k);
  until (Summand < MaxError);
  Reihe := Summe;
end;

function IntegralChi (chisqr : Real; f : longint) : Real;
var
  s : Real;
begin
  S := power((0.5 * chisqr), f/2) * Reihe(sqrt(chisqr), f)
                  * exp((-chisqr/2) - LnGamma((f + 2) / 2));
  IntegralChi := 1 - s;
end;
```

It works quite good for relatively big results.

For example:

For `Chi = 1.142132` and `df = 1` I'm getting `p` about `0.285202`, which is perfect. Same as `SPSS` result or other programs.

But for example `Chi = 138.609137` and `df = 4` I should recieive something about `0.000000`, but I'm getting floating point overflow error in `Reiche` function. `Summe` and `Summand` are very big then.

I admit that understanding distribution function is not my strong point, so maybe someone will tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you very much for the information

Comment: Use code from netlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should debug your program and find that there is an overflow
in your loop for k=149. For k=148 the value of Bruch is 3.3976725289e+304. The  next computation of Bruch overflows. A fix is to code

```
for i := 1 to k do
  Bruch := Bruch / (f + 2 * i);
Summand := power(chi, 2 * k) * Bruch;
```

With this change you get the value  `IntegralChi(138.609137,4) = 1.76835197E-7` after 156th iteration.

Note that your computation (even for this simple algorithm) is sub-optimal
because you compute the Bruch value over and over again. Just update it once
per loop:

```
function Reihe (chi : Real; f : Real) : Real;
  const MaxError = 0.0001;
var
  Bruch,
  Summe,
  Summand : Real;
  k    : longint;
begin
  Summe := 1;
  k := 1;
  Bruch := 1;
  repeat
    Bruch := Bruch / (f + 2 * k);
    Summand := power(chi, 2 * k) * Bruch;
    Summe := Summe + Summand;
    k := succ(k);
  until (Summand < MaxError);
  Reihe := Summe;
end;
```

Similar consideration should be applied to compute `power(chi, 2*k)` and then combine this with the improved evaluation of Bruch.

**Edit:** As a response to your comment, here the improved version based on the property of the power function, that is `power(chi, 2*(k+1)) = power(chi, 2*k)*sqr(chi)`

```
function Reihe (chi : Real; f : Real) : Real;
  const MaxError = 0.0001;
var
  chi2,
  Summe,
  Summand : Real;
  k    : longint;
begin
  Summe := 1;
  k := 1;
  Summand := 1;
  chi2 := sqr(chi);
  repeat
    Summand := Summand * chi2 / (f + 2 * k);
    Summe := Summe + Summand;
    k := succ(k);
  until (Summand < MaxError);
  Reihe := Summe;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works perfectly. I have checked the results of this function for 40 different SPSS results and are completely compatible. However, I do not fully understand this:

"Similar consideration should be applied to compute power(chi, 2*k) and then combine this with the improved evaluation of Bruch." because this element of the code has already been improved? When it comes to code performance, I really do not need it. :)